# Advice on failed audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just [failed this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5701412) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568712/why-does-frp-consider-time-as-a-factor-for-values). I failed a few in the past that were borderline, but this one feels way out of bounds, to me. It asks no fewer than seven individual questions, many of which appear to be primarily opinion based (but I picked too broad). Am I way off base here?

Comment: It's hard to be unbiased if you already know the "correct" response, but I think I would have failed this one as well. "Too Broad" was my first reaction.

Comment: ["Bring a “human factor” into review audit composition/selection"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773)

Comment: The thing is that different language "subgroups" have slightly different standards on whether a post is close-worthy or not. If you don't have knowledge of the language in question (e.g. in an audit), it can be hard to understand it in context.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are way off base here.  You should take time to understand a question and the core of what someone is trying to communicate rather than going through a checklist of hard and fast rules which were intended to be guidelines.  Programmers treating humans and human communication like computers and strict protocols are eating away at the usefulness and comunity aspect of Stack Overflow.  We can keep Stack Overflow and related sites clean without resorting to over-moderation.

Answer (score 21):

It doesn't ask seven different questions. It asks one question, but asks it in seven different ways, to make it as clear as possible to the reader what the OP is specifically interested in. That isn't too broad.

As for primarily opinion-based, that's a tough call. It's generally very hard to tell whether a "why" question asks for merely an opinion, or for the technical differences between the different approaches. The former asks for opinions and should be closed, the latter asks for facts and should be kept open. Personally, I would have skipped the question, because I'm not familiar enough with the material to make that call. If I *had* to vote, I must admit I probably would have voted to close it too. In a way, I guess that makes it a useful audit: if you don't know what to do, do leave the question for someone else.

Comment: *"I would have skipped the question, because I'm not familiar enough with the material to make that call."* I once [suggested exactly the same thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164299/172601) and got downvoted very heavily...

Comment: @WillNess To be fair, that's not exactly what you suggested. Although I do agree that people shouldn't be voting if they cannot tell whether a question or answer is a good one, I also feel people should be able to make that call themselves. I know I've voted on questions and answers in the past that your suggestion says I shouldn't (be allowed to) vote on. I'd like to think I make sure I can judge the worth of a post before voting, and that plenty of others do so as well, even if you can find counterexamples.

Comment: "exactly" not in the means, but in the goals... If everyone were acting responsibly, like you suggest, I wouldn't feel the need to propose that. But I've seen some cavalier attitudes on this issue, both in actual actions and in responses to that post of mine, like "I'm entitled to it, and I couldn't care less!". That's clearly not what you advocating. Maybe some clarification on this could be made in the FAQ or something...