# Fake tags in audits

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I've just got that question to the audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/29403665

I'm filtering questions using 'Java'. I've seen the question with the tag 'Java' with a syntax that doesn't even look like a Java and I've almost closed it as a crap question, but I wanted to check what is the 'Julia' library because I've never heard of that. And then I've found out, that it's a reasonable question made looking crappy by adding random tags.

Is it the way it should work? Because for people concentrating on one language, it doesn't work well.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean about "fake tags", [[tag:julia]] is a real tag/ programming language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This review is obviously an audit. Is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288046/this-review-is-obviously-an-audit-is-this-a-bug) TL;DR - audits are supposed to be easy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusing review audits caused by adding unrelated tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272249/confusing-review-audits-caused-by-adding-unrelated-tags)

Comment: [Your review was inappropriate - sorry, but it wasn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368048/11682469)

Comment: Julia is a legitimate tag the review audit appears to be legitimate.  Just because you filter reviews by a specific tag (or by answer/question) doesn’t mean you won’t get audits randomly